# How to disable or customize admin bar in back-end

Tags: admin-bar

To hide admin bar in front end, we put code in *functions.php*

```
//hide admin bar

    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

//or hook action

    function remove_admin_bar() {
            show_admin_bar( false );
    }
    add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_admin_bar');
```

but how to disable or customize admin bar (*wpadminbar*) in back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable *(or in the case which I show below with code, hiding)* the adminbar in the back-end you could use following code snippet.

> Please always backup `functions.php` before editing/adding code.

I added also a capability so the adminbar is still visible for the admin.
*(which you can remove if wish by removing `!current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) &&` or whatever you want to do with it (look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for other roles/capabilities, to understand all a little more) )*

```
/**
 * Hide the Toolbar(adminbar) in the back-end using CSS
 * 
 * @version WP 4.8
 * Read more {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities}
 *           {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin}
 *           {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can}
 */
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && is_admin() )
{
    function wpse271937_hide_adminbar()
    {
        ?>
        <style>
            #wpadminbar {
                display: none;
            }
            #wpwrap {
                top: -30px;/** change to own preference */
            } 
        </style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'wpse271937_hide_adminbar'); 
}
```

To customize the adminbar I leave that to your own preferences, but you can for sure take a look [here](https://generatewp.com/toolbar/) or maybe in the [Codex](https://wordpress.org/search/toolbar) itself.

Take also a look at these:

- [`wp_before_admin_bar_render`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render)
- [`admin_head` (plugin page)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-(plugin_page))

I hope this helps you on your way.

> Note: the **Screen Options** and **Help** tab are with the function as shown above still visible which imho is important. Of course is it also possible to hide/remove them with a *(seperate)* function.

Comment: Thank you! It's working when hiding it with css code..Generatewp.com is the good page for rendering code automatically.

Comment: @Rei, would be nice to see the answer be accepted so this topic can be closed.

Comment: Yes. It's solved